# Iterating over the content of a text file line by line having limitation, working but not finishing the entire text

Tags: java, for-loop, iterator, limit

I'm working on a Java method that will parse in a eternal for-loop a text line by line.

As you see I'm assigning the content of a `bufferReader` to a list

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/feed.txt"));
            String strLine;
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();    
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                list.add(strLine);
```

This work perfectly and the `feed.txt` content is totally assigned to the `arrayList` with 18238 line.

But when I tried to use and process the content of the list with an iterator in a for-loop (the following code), there is a problem:

```
Iterator itr;  
for (itr = list.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) { 
    String str = itr.next().toString();
}
```

The instructions (business processes) in the loop are working perfectly until the line number 5175 when the program stop his iteration. It is a problem linked to the iterator.

I think it is about the iterator because there isn't something special about this line, even by deleting it. The problem persist.

Does the iterator have a limitation? How can I rise it?

I'm trying to parse a file having this number of line, but I'm supposed to develop into my project an eternal never ending loop, receiving line all the time .

Can you help me please ?

Comment: How do you know that the first part worked perfectly? Why can't you combine the two into one loop? What error do you get? Is it just " no more data"?

Comment: Waybe your iterator works fine but your first step dont insert lines to the array as you think

Comment: how do you recommend for me to combine both of them (i'm a begginer)? the first step worked fine because when I displayed the content of my file, it does without a problem.
there is no exception displayed into my output when I run my program.
I realized that it isnt taking all the text by displaying the iterator content. System.out.println(str);

Answer (score 0):

A few things here:

First of all, use

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then you can just iterate using

```
for (String str : list) {
  // do something
}
```

Does that solve the problem?

Comment: java compiles that into a while loop using the lists iterator so if it's an Iterator problem it would persist.

Comment: @BlankChisui yeah, that's true, but it leaves less room for typos

Comment: @MichaelA I believe you should program against interfaces rather than implementations. Doesn't really matter, but it's cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You asked "how do I combine"? Here is a simple example. Note it does NOT use an iterator - so you will just be able to see that you are able to do something with all the lines in the input file. It's not really answering your question, but it should help you narrow down where the problem lies.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/feed.txt"));
String strLine, str;
int numLines;
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();    
numLines = 0;
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    list.add(strLine);
    System.out.println(list.get(numLines));
    numLines++;
    // do whatever you were going to do with the iterator here
    str = strLine.toString();
}

System.out.printf("Read in %d lines; the last line read is \n%s\n", numLines, list.get(numLines-1));
```

While this is not exactly what you were asking, when you run this code and see how it fails you will be a step closer to solving your stated problem.

Comment: I have made as you recommand for me , the problem is still showing up .

Comment: What did your output look like? What, in particular, was the last line of the output (the one that tells you how many lines were read in, and what the last line was)? Is that the number of lines you are expecting in the file? Did it make it all the way to the last line? What does "the problem is still showing up" mean? The more precise you are, the better your chances of getting some help...